# Explanation of options(flags) for bash

Tags: bash, options

I often see scripts with usage of **options** as in `if [ -f some_file ]` checks whether `some_file` is a file. I have a very vague understandings of **flags**, but can someone give me a good explanation? Others like `-p`, `-s`, I have no clue what they are and was unable to find good resources on them as a single google search doesn't yield any good result.

Comment: Are you asking about "[]" command? That is basically called test command in Bash. Just lookup the man page of test.

Comment: no, I am asking about options, a character follows by a "-"

Comment: You are asking for the option for test command. When you execute "man test" and look through it, you can see all the options(i.e, -f = FILE exists and is a regular file, -p FILE = exists and is a named pipe, etc.)

Comment: Go to the official documentation https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions

Comment: basic examples and explanations can also be found here:  http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/find-out-if-file-exists-with-conditional-expressions.html

Comment: Requests for learning materials are off-topic on here.  I've edited your question title and body to request an explanation instead.

Answer (score 4):

Believe it or not, `[` is actually another name for `test` command.

You can check the `man` page:

```
man test
```

`test` is a shell builtin too in most shells (and it gets precedence over the external one):

```
% type -a \[
[ is a shell builtin
[ is /usr/bin/[

% type -a test
test is a shell builtin
test is /usr/bin/test
```

In `bash` you can also see `help test`.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is the manual for bash, yes the simple `man bash`.

To find the exact entry in the manual, execute this command:

```
LESS=+/'^CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS' man bash
```

When working inside a bash shell, this also helps:

```
help test
```